# How do you pull text in dd attribute with no name using selenium and python?

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I have a webpage with a dd value. Here is the code:

```
<dd itemprop="youSave" 
class="saleprice pricingSummary-priceList-value" 
style="width: 50%; height: 20px; text-align: left; padding-left: 8px; line-height: 16px;">
$467.99</dd>
```

How do I pull the price ($467.99) using selenium and python and also remove the dollar sign?

Here is my current code which pulls the price_saved but can't get attribute:

```
try:
    while True:
        price_saved = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//dl[@class='dl']//dd")
        print("ok")
        saved_print = price_saved.get_attribute("*Don't know what to put here*")
        print("k")
        print(saved_print)
        i = i + 1
except:
    print("failed")
```

Comment: It would help to see your current code.

Comment: Just edited it to show my current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some possibilities depending on overall html

```
#class selector

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.pricingSummary-priceList-value').text.replace('$','')

#attribute selector
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[itemprop=youSave]').text.replace('$','')

#combined
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[itemprop=youSave].pricingSummary-priceList-value').text.replace('$','')

#combined with type selector
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('dd[itemprop=youSave].pricingSummary-priceList-value').text.replace('$','')
```

Example with list comprehension if multiple matches wanted (`find_elements` returns a list):

```
[i.text.replace('$','') for i in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('[itemprop=youSave]')]
```

class is faster than type which is faster than attribute. Shorter combinations can be faster than long dependant to some extent on rules given before and ordering but that is beyond scope of here.

I have used a single class of the multi-valued class. You can add in other class

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.saleprice.pricingSummary-priceList-value').text.replace('$','')
```